# Migrating JS files from Rails project to vanilla JS client side project and getting ERR 404 on ES6 import statements

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, web, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I had created a web app on top of a Rails gem and now due to an issue with the gem, I need to migrate it 100% over to JS. In my Rails project file, there was a folder called 'javascript' where all of my JS files lived and I defined a single entry point for my JS code and used ES6 import statements. Everything was working fine.

Now I'm trying to port the JS files over to my new empty project using just html / css / JS and leverage the existing import statements I created, and I'm getting a 404 error on my import statements, e.g.,

`GET https://myapp.netlify.app/javascript/shopify_app/business_logic/process_weight_on_interval net::ERR_ABORTED 404`

I feel like I'm definitely doing something wrong since it doesn't seem right that a JS file should be pointed to like that - right?

In my html file I have:

`<script type="module" src="weight.js"></script>`

At the top of my weight.js file (which is causing the error):

`import { processApiResponse } from "./javascript/shopify_app/business_logic/process_weight_on_interval";`

My html files and weight.js are in the home directory of the project, and then I copied over the 'javascript' folder from my Rails project which includes all of the other JS files. I'm relatively new to web development and admit I lack a strong understanding of ES6 import vs. ES5 require, modules, using script src, etc. and also which is appropriate for server vs. client side JS. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out - I simply have to add .js to the end of each path in my import statements :headsmack: